# How to replace consecutive special characters with single space ? using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to replace consecutive special characters with single space using JavaScript?

My string:

```
var format = 'ASDFG#@!$QWER';
```

I'm using this code:

```
format.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ' ')
```

It replaces single special characters with single space. I want to replace all consecutive special characters with single space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `+` to indicate one or more or something. So in your case you would use:

```js
var format='Test#@!$Test!#@Test#Test' 
let rep = format.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g, ' ') 

console.log(rep)
```

You can also use `\W+` for one or more non-word characters however it doesn't include `_`. It is equivalent to `/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/`. You could include it with `[\W+_]+`:

```js
var format = 'Test#_@!$Test!#@Test#Test'
let rep = format.replace(/[\W_]+/g, ' ')

console.log(rep)
```